# How can I set windows 10 notification preferences for my application

Tags: windows, qt, notifications, toast

I'm showing my application messages with `QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage()` function, and I want them to stay in Windows Action Center after them showing.
I found solution by setting *"Show notification in action center"* parameter, but how can I set this parameter with code from my application?

[Settings -> Notifications & Actions -> this parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlF82.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to [setup a COM server](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/blob/master/CPP/DesktopToastsSample.cpp) for you to be able to extend the timeout period of the message in the Action Center.